# AngularJS don't send data to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, server

Im new with NodeJS and Im trying to send data to server with Angular

```
$scope.logearse = function () {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/login",
            data: $scope.usuario
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
                console.log(response)
        }, function errorCallback(error){
            alert("No se han podido enviar los datos")
        })
    }
```

But in the server when I try to receipt the request is always `{}`

```
http.createServer(function(peticion, respuesta){

    console.log(peticion.url)
    console.log(peticion)
    // We begin with "login"

    if (peticion.url == "/login") {
        console.log("Inside of Login)

        var datosUsuarioLogin = '';

        peticion.addListener("data", function(chunk) {
            datosUsuarioLogin += chunk;

        // function called when a new chunk of data is recibed
        });

        peticion.addListener("end", function() {
            // When the data is recibed is transformed in JSON
            var datosUsuarioLoginObjeto = querystring.parse(datosUsuarioLogin);
            recuperarDatos(datosUsuarioLoginObjeto, respuesta);
            console.log(datosUsuarioLoginObjeto) //return {}
        });
        //End of LOGIN "if"
    }
    }).listen(8888)
```

The thing is the same code works if I use a form with a regular submit but no if I try to use the $http of ANGULAR.

I try to use "params" instead of "data" but "params" transform the data in the URL and the code dont works.

Comment: Are you setting proper headers along with the request like 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: If that's the case,we probably need to confirm what's happening with $scope.usuario. .

Comment: Those non-English comments in the code aren't helping

Comment: Comments in English now. $scope.usuario is a Json. And I use 'Content-Type': 'application/json' without succes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `bodyParser` to parse the request body and place the result in request.body of route.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

And the request:

```
$http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/login",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: $scope.usuario // if usuario is not a valid json, you could to use JSON.stringify($scope.usuario);
```

Comment: I still dont use express, yet. I want to learn how to build the app without express (or others addons) and later learn how to use that addons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of time trying finnaly I use Express but the version of Express I use dont allow simply bodyParser I need to install the body parser middleware
 [Link to body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

And the code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/', jsonParser, function (request, response) {
response.send(request.body) 
});
```